# Python GDB debug segfault Docker

Tags: python, docker, gdb

I am running a program in Python and debugging with GDB. I generated the coredump, but it basically gives me no information:

```
root@2380bca38221:/tmp# gdb python-dbg core.09e129943799.python.1547434680 
...

Reading symbols from python-dbg...done.

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 8]
Core was generated by `python /mounts/target/scripts/run_experiment_from_doodad.py'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f1fba3ac269 in ?? ()
(gdb) py-bt
Traceback (most recent call first):
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f1fba3ac269 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f1fba3ac390 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000007 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

[Coredump file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3ynpbr5g1afq13/core.09e129943799.python.1547434680?dl=0)

Comment: What is `python-dbg` and how does it relate to `python` that actually crashed? You probably want to use this `core` with `python`, and not `python-dbg`.

Comment: I tried both; googling led me to python-dbg as the correct program